# Bonobo Git Server Domain Authentication failes

Tags: git, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, bonobo

I recently installed Bonobo.Git.Server on one of my machines. I have a domain controller that I have the authentication wired through with settings in IIS.
If I'm logged into a computer/user that is part of the domain I can do a "git clone" just fine. However if I'm connected to non-domain machine and try to clone it will ask for the username and password but when I enter them it says "Authentication failed for: ..."

I have tried as many different for the url I can find.

```
git clone https://{username}@{url}.git
git clone https://{domain}@{username}@{url}.git
git clone https://{domain}\{username}@{url}.git
git clone https://{username}:{password}@{url}.git
git clone https://{domain}@{username}:{password}@{url}.git
git clone https://{domain}\{username}:{password}@{url}.git
```

I've also tried different combinations for the username when it asks for the username and password because it wasn't provided in the url. None of them seem to work.

I am able to access the bonobo git server webpage and view all the repositories just fine. But I cannot seem to clone a repository.
Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add extra slashes to the portion that specifies the domain. For example:

```
git clone https://{domain}\\\{username}@{url}.git
```

I'm not sure if this is an artifact of Bonobo itself or just IIS, either way, the current version (3.6.0) requires it.

Answer (score 0):

You must load your webpage first somehow:    URL/Bonobo.Git.Server/Repository/Index
URL must full e.g.
http://computername.domain.com but not http://computername
Hope it can help, I took quite a long time to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

Yes using **@** when you get user prompted works, specially if you follow literally the instructions to setup windows authentication for Bonobo Git Server:

http://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/